# How do I merge pull requests into a legacy branch?

Tags: git, merge, branch, legacy

So I created a branch to keep it as a snapshot of the current state of my project. I called it "v1".

I then refactored some code and commited to the master branch. So now I have the latest and greatest in master.

My question is: How do I maintain the old branch if someone submits a pull request to master? Is there an easy way to merge a pull request to both branches?

What I'm expecting is: if the file has changed a lot, then a conflict would appear. But if not, then it would merge only the changes introduced by the PR, even if the base of the PR is ahead of my legacy "v1" branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git fetch <remote>
git merge <remote>/<ref>
```

Where `remote` is the name of the remote branch that the pull request originated from and `ref` is the identifier of the commit (or branch) requesting the pull.  So if you have the main repository as a remote named `upstream` and that repo has a pull request based off of `5d4434e` (like this [repository's pull request](https://github.com/github/android/pull/460/commits)).  You would run:

```
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/5d4434e
```

This will merge that commit and all of the history missing from your local repo.  If you wanted to merge just that commit's changes and not all of the history, you may want `git cherry-pick upstream/5d4434e`.

Comment: So git merge wouldn't work for me because I don't want my refactoring changes to go to the legacy branch. I guess I'd have to use git cherry-pick for every commit in a pull request.

Comment: You'll probably have to cherry pick every commit in the pull request (which hopefully isn't too many)..since I don't think the actual information of a pull request is stored in the repository.

Comment: I guess this would work: git cherry-pick -m 1 <sha of the merge commit>

Comment: Good find @Renato, didn't know that `-m` existed. That should save some time.